# How to access command bus in CQRS

Tags: spring-boot, event-handling, microservices, spring-cloud, cqrs

This entire code is available at: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/API-MicroServices-Kafka/tree/master/Microservices-CQRS-SAGA-Kafka

I have the following use case diagram:

[image]

**ProductsCommandController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductsCommandController {

    private final Environment env;
    private final CommandGateway commandGateway;

    @Autowired
    public ProductsCommandController(Environment env, CommandGateway commandGateway) {
        this.env = env;
        this.commandGateway = commandGateway;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createProducts(@RequestBody CreateProductRestModel createProductRestModel) throws InterruptedException {

        CreateProductCommand createProductCommand = CreateProductCommand.builder()
                .price(createProductRestModel.getPrice())
                .quantity(createProductRestModel.getQuantity())
                .title(createProductRestModel.getTitle())
                .productId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).build();

        String returnValue = commandGateway.sendAndWait(createProductCommand);

        return returnValue;

    }

}
```

**CreateProductCommand**

```
@Builder
@Data
public class CreateProductCommand {
    
    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    private final String productId;
    private final String title;
    private final BigDecimal price;
    private final Integer quantity;
    
}
```

**ProductEventsHandler**

```
@Component
public class ProductEventsHandler {

    private final ProductsRepository productsRepository;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductEventsHandler.class);

    public ProductEventsHandler(ProductsRepository productsRepository) {
        this.productsRepository = productsRepository;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void on(ProductCreatedEvent event) {

        ProductEntity productEntity = new ProductEntity();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(event, productEntity);

        try {
            productsRepository.save(productEntity);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**ProductsRepository**

```
public interface ProductsRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductEntity, String> {
    
    ProductEntity findByProductId(String productId);
    ProductEntity findByProductIdOrTitle(String productId, String title);

}
```

While working on CQRS, I am across the following statement:

*So now that we have command object created, we are ready to send this command to command Gateway and we will inject command gateway object into our controller class. And command Gateway is an object that will be used to send this command object that we have created to a command bus. So think of Command Gateway as of an API to send commands and command bus is a mechanism that receives this command and routes this command to a command handler.*

**My Question is as follows:**

What kind of **Command Bus** is created. Can we replace this bus with other devices like queues/topics/kafka. If yes how can we do that.

Also, is it possible to see the content of the bus.

Please guide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka and the like are quite usable as a command bus in that architecture.  In the case of Kafka, a topic (or perhaps more properly a partition of a topic, as ordering is only guaranteed within a partition) would typically be a command bus.

In general a command bus (as it seems to be used in this context) might not allow seeing its contents (e.g. commands could be sent via HTTP endpoints; unless the handler for that endpoint also happens to persist the command somewhere (an example of command sourcing), you wouldn't be able to (absent things like packet capturing) see the contents of the bus); whether or not a command bus should be introspectable and/or persistent is definitely a consideration when designing/choosing/implementing one.